# correct use of "tear up" in a sentence

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs, grammar-myths

> She was so angry that she tore the letter up.

I'd like to know whether the use of the phrase "tore the letter up" in the above sentence is correct or not, or whether it should be "tore up the letter".

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's wrong? We're here to help you understand why things are correct or incorrect, not to merely tell you if they are correct or not, so please tell us more about your sentence and what you want to understand.

Comment: I ask this question because some teachers say it is wrong. They said it will be correct only if I rewrite as "She was so angry that she tore up the letter". I hop this  helps.

Answer (score 2):

In normal use, and certainly here, both are fine. However, it is usually safer to keep the two words in such a phrasal verb as close together as possible. The more you **split** gratuitously, monstrously, and wickedly the poor defenseless, words, who have done no harm to anyone at all **apart**, the more difficult it is to read. See [this question and answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77472/is-there-any-rule-about-splitting-phrasal-verbs) over on the main EL site for more details.

Comment: While 'tore the letter up' and 'tore up the letter' are both fine, and while I agree with tkp's advice that it is usually safer to keep the two words together, note that 'it' cannot come at the end: 'She read the letter. She was so angry that she tore it up' (NOT 'that she tore up it'). So keeping 'up ' and the end may be safer if you are going to refer to 'the letter' and 'it' interchangeably.